# Examples of Materials with a Coefficient of Kinetic Friction Very Close to or Equal to Coefficient of Static Friction?

Tags: materials, friction, material-science, surface-modelling

I'm looking for examples of frictional materials that have a coefficient of kinetic friction that is as close to equal to their coefficient of static friction as possible.

What is an example of that kind of material (on Earth)? Is there a database of real-world materials that can tell me about this?

Comment: Many books have lists of material characteristics - worth looking,

Comment: most materials have the kinetic friction close to static friction. Do you have an absolute threshold or relative difference in mind?

Comment: coefficients of friction are for pairs of materials, not just one. Try PTFE (teflon) on PTFE (teflon), perhaps

Comment: @NMech I don't, but if there's any particularly notable material pairings or a ranked order of those kinds of materials (the *least* difference possible) that would be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steel/Teflon - $\mu_s = \mu_k = 0.27$

Glass/Teflon - $\mu_s = \mu_k = 0.1$

Ice/Ice - $\mu_s = \mu_k = 0.01$

See table [here](https://mechguru.com/machine-design/typical-coefficient-of-friction-values-for-common-materials/).